# Margin Usage on Body

Tags: website-design, web-app, guidelines, dashboard, margin

My team is working on creating a dashboard and we’re having a bit of a conflict as to whether the body of the website should have a margin or not. The above image is the dashboard with the margin and the bottom image is fullscreen. I want to know if it’s bad practice to have a margin on the whole body ad shown in the top image.

[image]

Comment: You're asking about margin but there's also **rounded boundaries** a.k.a `(border-radius)`, so differentiating these two important. One can say using margins without round corners applied to the layout.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: It’s not bad practice, but it’s bad design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no benefits for this either on a UX point of view or UI point of view. To create a pleasing visual interface using the margin around the body you would need a bigger margin that will cost you some estate without benefits so short answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

White space is required in a web page if there is a issue with white patch on the screen. It is better to run the color and have space before and after the code. Additionally, it is easy to code and manage pages with a standard guidelines. Like this page also has some margin in every side.